# Check if td contains text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a small project and I need the functionality where the table rows are hidden if their td.icaoIata  do not contain the string that is being typed in the input bar. 
On top of that, they are hidden/displayed if their data- attribute is in range of a Jquery slider. That part I got working, and shouldn't be relevant.

Basically, if the string is not found, hide the row. Then, once the input box is updated, check again, and hide/show if still not found/found.

My troubles were mostly with combining different functions such as find(), :contains etc which I couldn't get to work together.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Can anyone guide me to a solution?

Here is my code.
Thanks a bunch!

```
 <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control searchinput" ><br>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="slider-value-lower"></div>
<div id="slider-value-upper"></div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Flight #</th>
                <th>Departure</th>
                <th>Arrival</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Aircraft</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
                <th>Options</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="schedules">
            <tr class="schedulerow" data-duration="1.4"> 
                <td><a href="">DLH1058</a></td>
                <td class="icaoIata">Frankfurt Main <small>(EDDF)</small></td>
                <td class="icaoIata">Cote D'Azur <small>(LFMN)</small></td>
                <td> 1.4 h</td>
                <td class="icaoIata">
                    A320 
                </td>
                <td>386 nm</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">Book</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            ............

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And my JS

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {

    connect: true,
    start: [0,3],
    step: 0.5,
    tooltips: true,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 20
    }
});
//initialize the values
$(".schedules").children().hide().filter(function() {
    var duration = $(this).data('duration');
    return duration >= 0 && duration <= 3;
}).addClass('is-shown').show();

$(".searchinput").keyup(function() {
    var content = $(".searchinput").val();
    //My mess was here....
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('change', function( values, handle ) {

    /*sliderValues[handle].innerHTML = values[handle];*/
    filterRows(values[0], values[1]);
});

function filterRows(min, max) {
    $(".schedules").children().removeClass('is-shown').hide().filter(function() {
        var duration = $(this).data('duration');
        return duration >= min && duration <= max;
    }).addClass('is-shown').show();
}
```

So,

Comment: which `td.icaoIata`? i can see more than 1 if i am not mistaken

Comment: Please try with this plugin
https://datatables.net/

Comment: It should search all marked with icaoIata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the filter you're already applying can be set from multiple sources (the slider and the input box), I would keep a separate object where the filter settings are kept (also useful for DRY setting of the values)

e.g.

```
var filter ={
  min: 0,
  max: 3,
  text : ''
};
```

where min and max are the durations and text is the search text.

The `filterRows` method can use the filter object and doesn't need the parameters:

```
function filterRows() {
    $(".schedules").children().removeClass('is-shown').hide().filter(function() {
        var duration = $(this).data('duration');
        return duration >= filter.min && duration <= filter.max
            && (!filter.text || $(this).children('td.icaoIata').filter(function(){return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.text) !== -1;}).length);
    }).addClass('is-shown').show();
}
```

The slider and input should set the proper filter values and call the `filterRows` method.

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyw4r3rz/)

Comment: I will try and report back!

Comment: Works like a charm. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for that.

```
var content = $(".searchinput").val();

$('.schedules tr')
    .show() // first show all tr
    .filter(function () {
        // return only tr that does not contain "content" value
        var match = false;

        $(this).find('.icaoIata').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(content) == -1) {
                match = true;
            }
        });

        return match;
    })
    .hide();
```

Comment: I will try and report back. Thanks for your effort!